# Selenium XPATH Returns Empty Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I visited: http://132.247.137.206/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/mainFrame.cgi

and wrote the following in python (after waiting for page to load)

```
try:
    tmp = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Login"]')
    print(tmp)
except Exception as e:
    print('NONE FOUND!')
```

But all I see being printed is:

```
[]
```

Why is that?

I'm expecting the above code to return ay item in the page link or button that has the word Login.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` denotes empty list as the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used doesn't identifies the element within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Deep Dive

The element with text as ***Login*** is within an [`<frame>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447):

[image: login]

---

### Solution

To identify the element you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("http://132.247.137.206/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/mainFrame.cgi")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@title='Header Area']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Login']"))))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="224f5eafafd1c7422d408810378cd6ec", element="d4e316c3-3187-42e9-b1d2-054cbab92f0b")>
  ```

Comment: Thank you, what can be done for general case? Ie. looking for any button or link with the text login? I don't know what the frame name will be either

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: Plus question, why do I need to switch to the frame first? why can't selenium just find it as if it was outside frame